# Travis environmental variable to check pull request label?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, travis-ci

I would like to mark some of my pull requests with a label and check it at `after_script` so that I send my application to HockeyApp only if the label is (or isn't) present.

Is it possible?

I was searching for an answer and came across [this post](https://graysonkoonce.com/getting-the-current-branch-name-during-a-pull-request-in-travis-ci/) which suggests using `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH` to get branch name. That way, I could mark it by giving it specific prefix and check that in my script. But that doesn't sound like a best idea.